# jquery accordion slide-up and slide-down menu not works

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

i try to implement the accordion jquery for toggle slide down and slide up left navigation bar but i use the below jquery and the html code. But it not works it just show the "click here" only.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery("#accordion > li > div").click(function () {

                if (false == $(this).next().is(':visible')) {
                    jQuery('#accordion ul').slideUp(300);
                }
                jQuery(this).next().slideToggle(300);
            });
            jQuery('#accordion ul:eq(0)').show();

        </script>
```

here is my code in html:

```
<ul id="accordion">
            <li>
                <div>
                   Click here</div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"</a>outer view</li>
                    <li><a href="#"</a>our works</li>
                    <li><a href="#"</a>Atrs</li>
                    <li><a href="#"</a>contac us</li>
                    <li><a href="#"</a>Demo</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you didn't forget:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Put all your jQuery goodness in here.
});
```

[http://docs.jquery.com/](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Introducing_$%28document%29.ready%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

In your line 2 jQuery ("accordion > li > div"), shouldn't it be

```
jQuery("#accordion > li > div").
```

I suggest you try checking for syntax errors with [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28software%29) or the JavaScript console in Firefox...